# CSS Как запускать уже отработавшую анимацию в обратном направлении?

Tags: css, jquery, css3, css-animation

Подскажите, почему уже отработавшая анимация CSS не запускается в обратном направлении ? Приведу упрощенный пример.

```js
var couter = 0;

$(".myButton").on("click", function() {

  couter++;

  if (couter % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log("1");
    $(".wrapperBlock").addClass("effect_blur");
  } else {
    console.log("2");
    $(".wrapperBlock").removeClass("effect_blur").addClass("effect_blur__revers");
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.myButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrapperBlock {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300") 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.effect_blur {
  animation: 1.6s blurBackground 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.effect_blur__revers {
  filter: blur(30px);
  animation: 1.6s blurBackground 100ms linear alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes blurBackground {
  0% {
    filter: blur(0);
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapperBlock">

</div>
<button class="myButton">Button</button>
```

По нажатию нечетное количество на кнопку я хочу заблуривать фон, по четному количеству разблуривать. Я на втором шаге пробовал и просто для .effect_blur__revers {  animation-duration: revert;} задавать, но это тоже не помогает. Нету правильного взаимодействия с DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял о чём вы

```js
$('.myButton').on('click', function() {
  $('.wrapperBlock').toggleClass('wrapperBlock_blur');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.myButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrapperBlock {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300") 50% 50% no-repeat;
  filter: blur(0);
  transition: filter .3s ease;
}

.wrapperBlock_blur {
  filter: blur(30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapperBlock"></div>

<button class="myButton">Button</button>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, это решило вопрос. Только всё ещё осталось непонятно, почему на свойство animation не получилось реализовать обратный эффект.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, потому что у `animation` нет обратного действия, либо делать другую анимацию, которая с `filter: blur(30px)` на `filter: blur(0)` делает, либо так, второй способ, конечно же, лучше)

Comment: так ведь приведенный мною код, в самом первом сообщении, и должен был сделать "другую анимацию". По сути при нажатии второй раз на кнопку, я удалял класс в который была встроена анимация, потом резко назначал второй класс с разблуриным по умолчанию фоном который должен был открутить анимацию назад. Но не сработало же.

Comment: Сегодня, опробовал данный метод на живом примере, оказалось что в Safary очень плохо с (задержкой) transition-delay  свойством. Заблуривание происходило мгновенно.